# Users folder missing in windows 11

Tags: user-accounts, windows-11

I am not able to see the Users folder.
I was trying to move particular user folder to another drive since C drive space exhausted.
After doing that this issue is there. I am unable to unhide it.

I have tried other answers but not luck.
But still I am able access the folder using `C:\Users\` in address bar.

[image]

Comment: You would need to set up a new Windows User (member of Admin) and then see if you can take Ownership of your original data.  Also consider a much larger main drive.

Comment: Where path does %AppData% take you to?

Comment: @Ramhound To this folder `C:\Users\kkgow\AppData\Roaming`

Comment: @John . Even the current user has admin rights. But able to see the Users folder

Comment: So then make a new user and recover the data from the original user folder

Comment: Do I understand right that `%AppData%` takes you to a sub-folder of `C:\Users` that exists, but you cannot see `C:\Users`  when Explorer is displaying C:\ ? It might perhaps have become hidden for some reason. Ensure you can see hidden files in Explorer *View > Options > View*, where under "Hidden f‌iles and folders" check "Show hidden f‌iles, folders and drives" and click OK.

Comment: Can you navigate directly to C:\Users\kkgow\?

Comment: Yes @Ramhound. I able to directly navigate to kkgow folder when I type the address in address bar in top

Comment: Can you enable your File Explorer options to view hidden folders and update your screenshot

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems the folder was hidden. Unhiding it ,works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand your question correctly; sorry if erred. Up to now, we could look at users & groups by opening COM app to System Tools, scrolling down to Local Users etc. If you are running Win 11 HOME this folder is now absent.
The easiest work around is to use the third party snap in available free thru Gitmo lusrmgr GitHub page at: https://github.com/proviq/AccountManagement
Once downloaded, click to run. It will look very familiar. Won't give further details in case I misunderstood your query
If you are uncertain if you are running 11 HOME A) go to CMD prompt B) type in lusrmgr.msc If native snap in fails, you have a Home Version.
Last, even if missing the folder, you can still go in 1) Control Panel, 2)Open User Accounts & 3) Delete accounts or change credentials.
Best, An Old Lady